# Apache POI Large Excel Export is slow

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to convert CSV to Excel with Apache POI by using SXSSFWorkbook.

My CSV file has about 230,000 records and 50 columns. Total processing time for both read and write processes around 1 minute.

I am looking around to solve my performance issue to get lower times (max. 30 sec) since the connection time out occurs after 30 sec. from gateway.

What am I doing wrong? Is there anything I could change?

```
public static byte[] readCsvAndWriteExcel(String filePath, File csvFile) {
    logger.info("Read csv and write excel has been started for {}", csvFile.getName());

    String line;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = readFile(filePath);

    SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(SXSSFWorkbook.DEFAULT_WINDOW_SIZE);
    workbook.setCompressTempFiles(true);
    int rowNumber = 0;
    int cellNumber;
    SXSSFRow row;
    SXSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(FilenameUtils.getBaseName(csvFile.getName()));

    try {
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            cellNumber = 0;
            row = sheet.createRow(rowNumber++);
            addCell(cellNumber, row, line.trim().split(SEPERATOR_PATTERN));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("File is not found: {}", filePath, e);
        throw new Exception("Exception");
    }

    logger.info("Read csv and write excel has been finished for {}", csvFile.getName());
    return retrieveBytesOfXlsxFile(workbook);
}
```

And addCell method for saving cell and styling;

```
private static void addCell(int cellNumber, SXSSFRow row, String[] splitRow) {
    for (String field : splitRow) {
        SXSSFCell cell = row.createCell(cellNumber++);
        cell.setCellValue(field);
    }
}
```

Fastexcel gives same time with POI streaming.

Comment: workbook.setCompressTempFiles(true) will probably slow things down - do you need it?

Comment: @PJFanning In first, I didn't use this property and it didn't affect the duration much. Thanks, now i removed again.

Comment: https://github.com/apache/poi/blob/trunk/poi-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/examples/xssf/streaming/DeferredGeneration.java uses a slightly modified SXSSF approach but that can be used avoid temp files - so might run faster

Comment: https://github.com/dhatim/fastexcel also might be worth checking - its writer might be faster than SXSSFWorkbook - it supports fewer excel features but for simple xlsx files it could be a good solution

Comment: I am refactoring the code to work with fastexcel. I will keep update after I tried. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Still writing excel around 1 min with fastexcel..Interesting

Comment: It's just my opinion but I think xlsx is a bad format for large data file transfer. Would you consider something like CSV? xlsx is a zip of XML files with ugly cross references between the XML files - making it awkward to properly stream the file. A lot of people insist on persevering with xlsx because their users like it but sometimes you just have to abandon it. I would suggest that if you stick with xlsx that you update this issue with your findings.

Comment: @PJ Fanning: Not only your opinion. `Excel` is a spreadsheet calculation and not meant to use for data exchange.

Comment: We are offering two options to customers which are the csv and excel reports. Report needs to be downloaded with xlsx format since the records greater than 65k rows. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: The advice is not to use xlsx for large responses. If you don't like the advice, the problem is in your hands. If you persist you would be best to invest some time with using a Java profiler to track down the hotspot(s).

Comment: @PJFanning I consider myself a bit of an expert (more accurate above average) on Excel. Most developers don't know that the binary model used by the new Excel (OOXML) while it provides a smaller footprint for I/O, it is actually much larger in memory than the old Excel OLE2 model. I have done many experiments to verify this. Also, I believe POI publishes some info about this. Regardless of all that, Excel is not meant to be a database. Still, many people use it for this purpose which is 100% the incorrect use for this file type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with the way you write to Excel. Time is mainly wasted on the method of reading CSV. In addition, fastexcel is the best choice I tested, it is faster than others( SXSSFWorkBook ,easyexcel and myexcel).The following code hopes to be useful to you.

```java
import cn.hutool.core.io.FileUtil;
import cn.hutool.core.lang.Pair;
import cn.hutool.core.text.csv.CsvReader;
import cn.hutool.core.text.csv.CsvUtil;
import cn.hutool.core.text.csv.CsvWriter;
import com.alibaba.excel.EasyExcel;
import com.github.liaochong.myexcel.core.DefaultStreamExcelBuilder;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook;
import org.dhatim.fastexcel.Workbook;
import org.dhatim.fastexcel.Worksheet;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class ExcelTest {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExcelTest.class);

    /**
     * generate test xlsx (time < 15s)
     */
    @Test
    public void Test1() {
        LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.now();
        try (OutputStream os = FileUtil.getOutputStream("D:\\tmp\\TEST1.xlsx")) {
            Workbook wb = new Workbook(os, "MyApplication", "1.0");
            Worksheet ws = wb.newWorksheet("Sheet 1");
            HashMap<Pair<Integer, Integer>, String> dataMap = new HashMap<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 230000; i++) {
                String[] strings = new Random().ints(50, 100, 150).mapToObj(a -> "TEST_" + a).collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(new String[]{});
                for (int j = 0; j < 50; j++) {
                    ws.value(i, j, strings[j]);
                }
            }
            wb.finish();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Error", e);
        }
        LocalDateTime end = LocalDateTime.now();
        logger.info("Cost time {}", Duration.between(start, end).toMillis() + "ms");
    }

    /**
     * generate test csv  (time < 2s)
     */
    @Test
    public void Test2() {
        LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.now();
        try (CsvWriter writer = CsvUtil.getWriter("D:\\tmp\\TEST2.csv", StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
            writer.writeHeaderLine(IntStream.range(0, 50).mapToObj(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(new String[]{}));
            for (int i = 0; i < 230000; i++) {
                String[] strings = new Random().ints(50, 100, 150).mapToObj(a -> "TEST_" + a).collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(new String[]{});
                writer.writeLine(strings);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error", e);
        }
        LocalDateTime end = LocalDateTime.now();
        logger.info("Cost time {}", Duration.between(start, end).toMillis() + "ms");
    }

    /**
     * convert by fastexcel   (time < 15s)
     */
    @Test
    public void Test3() {
        LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.now();
        try (OutputStream os = FileUtil.getOutputStream("D:\\tmp\\TEST3.xlsx"); CsvReader reader = CsvUtil.getReader(FileUtil.getUtf8Reader("D:\\tmp\\TEST2.csv"))) {
            Workbook wb = new Workbook(os, "MyApplication", "1.0");
            Worksheet ws = wb.newWorksheet("Sheet 1");
            reader.stream().forEach(a -> {
                long originalLineNumber = a.getOriginalLineNumber();
                for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
                    ws.value((int) originalLineNumber, i, a.get(i));
                }
            });
            wb.finish();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Error", e);
        }
        LocalDateTime end = LocalDateTime.now();
        logger.info("Cost time {}", Duration.between(start, end).toMillis() + "ms");
    }

    /**
     * convert by SXSSFWorkbook  (time < 30s)
     */
    @Test
    public void Test4() {
        LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.now();
        try (CsvReader reader = CsvUtil.getReader(FileUtil.getUtf8Reader("D:\\tmp\\TEST2.csv")); OutputStream os = FileUtil.getOutputStream("D:\\tmp\\TEST4.xlsx"); SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(SXSSFWorkbook.DEFAULT_WINDOW_SIZE)) {
            SXSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet 1");
            reader.stream().forEach(a -> {
                long originalLineNumber = a.getOriginalLineNumber();
                SXSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((int) originalLineNumber);
                for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
                    SXSSFCell cell = row.createCell(i);
                    cell.setCellValue(a.get(i));
                }
            });
            workbook.write(os);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Error", e);
        }
        LocalDateTime end = LocalDateTime.now();
        logger.info("Cost time {}", Duration.between(start, end).toMillis() + "ms");
    }

    /**
     * convert by easyexcel  (time < 30s)
     */
    @Test
    public void Test5() {
        LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.now();
        try (CsvReader reader = CsvUtil.getReader(FileUtil.getUtf8Reader("D:\\tmp\\TEST2.csv"))) {
            EasyExcel.write("D:\\tmp\\TEST5.xlsx", ExcelTest.class).sheet("Sheet 1").needHead(false).doWrite(() -> reader.stream().collect(Collectors.toList()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Error", e);
        }
        LocalDateTime end = LocalDateTime.now();
        logger.info("Cost time {}", Duration.between(start, end).toMillis() + "ms");
    }

    private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    /**
     * convert by myexcel  (time < 30s)
     */
    @Test
    public void Test6() {
        LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.now();
        try (OutputStream os = FileUtil.getOutputStream("D:\\tmp\\TEST6.xlsx");
             Reader reader = FileUtil.getUtf8Reader("D:\\tmp\\TEST2.csv");
             CsvReader csvReader = CsvUtil.getReader();
             DefaultStreamExcelBuilder<Map> defaultExcelBuilder = DefaultStreamExcelBuilder.of(Map.class)
                     .threadPool(executorService)
                     .start()) {
            csvReader.setContainsHeader(true);
            List maps = csvReader.readMapList(reader);
            defaultExcelBuilder.asyncAppend(() -> maps);
            org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook workbook = defaultExcelBuilder.build();
            workbook.write(os);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Error", e);
        }
        LocalDateTime end = LocalDateTime.now();
        logger.info("Cost time {}", Duration.between(start, end).toMillis() + "ms");
    }

}
```

Dependencys:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.dhatim</groupId>
    <artifactId>fastexcel</artifactId>
    <version>0.12.12</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>cn.hutool</groupId>
    <artifactId>hutool-all</artifactId>
    <version>5.7.16</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
    <artifactId>easyexcel</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.liaochong</groupId>
    <artifactId>myexcel</artifactId>
    <version>3.11.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Test result:
[Test result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8v3xz.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi, thanks for testing all of the libraries and for your help. I rearrange the CSV reader part and turned into fastexcel, for 230.000 rows and 50 columns took 28 second which is not bad time. I will dive into code to make even better especially download part (outputstream).